# possible undefined local variable for loop condition

Tags: ruby, loops, rubymine

Rubymine flags the variable **found** as potentially undefined. I thought the answer would be to move the variable **found** outside the begin but I then go into a tight loop that never exits. I am sure this is a block scoping issue but lack the ruby experience to realise what the issue is. I am assuming that this is being flagged because **found** is declared inside the **begin**, so the question here is.. is this valid code or is Rubymine's inspector wrong in this instance ?

```
begin
  found = false
  @some_collection.keys.each do |key|
    found = evaluate_collection(@some_collection[key], key) unless found
  end
end while found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [rubyspec for while](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/language/while_spec.rb):

```
 it "executes code in containing variable scope" do
    i = 0
    while i != 1
      a = 123
      i = 1
    end

    a.should == 123
  end
```

As `begin...end while bool` is just another form of a `while` statement, it also executes in the containing variable scope:

```
begin
  found = 'asdf'
end while false
puts found
```

Will output `asdf`

Comment: yes so is the above code fine and the rubymine inspector incorrect ?

Comment: I believe so. I also use rubymine, and it occasionally gets scoping wrong for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor your code a little, so it shouldn't warn

```
found = false
while !found
  @some_collection.detect do |k, v|
    found = evaluate_collection(v, k)
  end
end
```

Or you can write it with recursion

```
find = lambda do |collection|
  collection.each do |k,v|
    return found if found = evaluate_collection(v, k)
  end
  find.call(collection)
end

found = find.call(@some_collection)
```

But without tail optimization it could fail with stack overflow :)